# Root mailbox permissions being changed

Tags: linux, sendmail

The permissions on my root mailbox /var/spool/mail/root (with user root:mail) are reset from `-rw-rw----` to `-rw-------` whenever "Mail Delivery Subsystem MAILER-DAEMON@drjack.info" sends a message to it.

This prevents mail sent to root@drjack.info from arriving in the root mailbox (instead it arrives at the fallthrough mailbox).  When permission is reset to `-rw-rw----` such mail does arrive at root, but the next delivery from "Mail Delivery Subsystem" changes the permission back to `-rw-------`

My mail setup uses sendmail and procmail on a Amazon Linux OS.  Trying to diagnose the problem with *"auditctl -w /var/spool/mail/root -p rwxa"* did not produce any audit records.  Have examined sendmail and procmail config files but do not see any lines which might bear on this.  Googling did not provide any answers.  Would appreciate any advice on where to look to solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Mailbox owned by root account itself => bad idea

`root`'s "super powers" should not be required to read emails to `root`.
Creating **needless** risk should be avoided.

You **SHOULD** create alias redirecting email addressed to too to non privileged account.

/etc/mail/aliases

```
root: name-of-non-privileged-account
```

**WARNING:** sendmail requires running command `newaliases` after modifying aliases file.

Comment: Is there a "why" that is a bad idea ??

Comment: @user48297 I have added short explanation,